# Difference b/w a $ git pull and $ hg pull

Tags: git, mercurial

[Steve Losh: A Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#one-more-difference-between-mercurial-and-git) -

> Mercurial will push/pull all branches by default, while git will push/pull only the current branch.

I wonder if my understanding is right:

It occurs to me that when I do a `git pull` I actually *do* `fetch` from all branches but the `merge` happens only with the current branch that I am sitting on. This is *very* close to `mercurial` where a `pull` gets me everything from the remote; but does *not* `merge` anything yet.

In `mercurial` a `push` sends everything, but an explicit `update`is needed to merge things back. I am not quite sure on `git'` behavior of the `push` operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Git, you have to pull/push all the branches one by one. Thus, you can work on local branches without messing up the server.

You can specify each time which branch you want to pull/push on : `git push origin master` means you want to push your branch master on the one at origin, which is often the "default" server.

Comment: In mercurial `hg push -r .` pushes just the current branch.  There's a `hg nudge` alias for that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `git pull` is done without any refspec is based on the config ( from the default behaviour section of git-pull man):

In order to determine what remote branches to fetch (and optionally store in the remote-tracking branches) when the command is run without any refspec parameters on the command line, values of the configuration variable remote..fetch are consulted, and if there aren’t any, $GIT_DIR/remotes/ file is consulted and its `Pull:` lines are used. In addition to the refspec formats described in the OPTIONS section, you can have a globbing refspec that looks like this:

refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html

Again what is pushed by `git push` depends on the configuration (and the paramaters)

Without additional configuration, works like `git push origin :`.

The default behavior of this command when no  is given can be configured by setting the push option of the remote.

For example, to default to pushing only the current branch to origin use git config remote.origin.push HEAD. Any valid  can be configured as the default for git push origin.

http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html